# Subversion, xcode and problem with project.pbxproj

Tags: xcode, version-control

We use subversion to keep track of our code, just sharing code between us two. However we encounter a problem when we both add or remove file at the same time before the next commit. It seems that whenever we mess with Groups & Files, project.pbxproj under the project package will be modified and subversion cannot take care of that. As a result the project cannot be opened.

My guess is that project.pbxproj keep track of how groups and files are arranged. How do I make this work under Subversion? It is a text file, but somehow it's doesn't seem to be treated as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, is the .pbxproj file getting corrupted, or is it that the changes you make are not correctly reflected in it? (ie if you remove a file, but do not have the update in the .pbxproj file, does it refuse to load?)

If the .pbxproj file is text, you can tell subversion to store it as such by setting the [svn:minme-type](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html) property.

Setting it to a text type will give you better merging, so whoever commits first save his changes, then when the other updates his working copy, the changes will be merged into the file. You should review changes when a merge occurs, even though subversion is good at this, its only a computer process and will not do what you expected occasionally.

Comment: It looks to me like getting corrupted at least in one of the options. It offers three options, not in my exact wording but (1) keep local changes, (2) overwrite local file with repository version, and (3) close xcode. If we close the Xcode it would not open, we had to manually delete it and update stuff from the command line. Then Xcode will open with the file hierarchy of the repository.

Comment: that sounds more like the merge tool kicking in and telling you it cannot perform the merge as there are conflicts (ie you both changed the same line - the tool can't  know which line to use). closing xcode and try with TortoiseSVN  on the file instead. Also set it to a text mime type and you will have better merging support.

Answer (score 1):

First, "Project.pbxproj" is a kind of file which keeps track of your XCode bundle updates such as any new file added, deleted, moved.

So you must have to commit this file when you are committing your source code.

If You couldn't open the project after updating, it is because your "Project.pbxproj" file got conflicted with the previous commit. So you have to resolve the issue by opening & editing it.

Usually when a conflict happens SVN adds 3 extra files.

1. your conflicted file.
2. your own file. (.mine)
3. latest committed file in svn.
4. an old versioned file on top of which you worked.

You need to compare and resolve the issue manually.

Other better way is, Keep latest committed file & remove conflicted, your own file & old version file. Rename the latest committed file as project.pbxproj

Now you can open the xcode project as the conflicted file is removed.

Just make sure you add & remove files previously you have done between last commit & conflict, to the target. Now, the latest commit file will have your changes in project. You can commit the project now to your Repository.

Hope it makes sense.